# Auto read OTP and allow pasting it while taping on Mobile browsers using javascript on MVC appliccaation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

Is there any way to read OTP and display it or fill it on the text box as shown below
[image: auto fill otp]

I am aware about WEB-OTP, but htis need specific OTP format. I am looking any way impiment it wothout any specific OTP format

please help me on this